# Madelung Constant

Tags: calculus, summation, physics, approximation, mathematica

I have been working in this series
$$\sum _{m=0}^{\infty } \sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \sum _{j=0}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^{j+k+m} \left((j+1)^2+(k+1)^2+(m+1)^2\right)}{\left((j+1)^2+(k+1)^2+(m+1)^2\right)^{3/2}}=0.132476$$
I used the Nsum as usual in Mathematica and it gives the result above, using different values of working precision I get similar answer, but a few different decimals.

Maple it is not capable of giving any value. I used another method and it gives similar values as above but this represents the madelung constant and it must be $\frac{-1,73.}{2}$ for the extended sum to -$\infty$. I do not know where is the error? Mathematica is wrong or the Levin Accelerator method is wrong too.

Comment: Why should the answer be $-\frac{1.73}2$?  What does $-\infty$ have to do with this?

Comment: When extending to negative infinity, there is a power of $\frac 12$ in the denominator and not a power of $\frac 32$ as in your question according to the [Wikipedia link photo](https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/a5834f867105ee42a1db3daca448b1c95df7f86c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sum is
$$
S=\sum_{j,k,m=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{j+k+m}}{\sqrt{(j+1)^2+(k+1)^2+(m+1)^2}}=-\sum_{j,k,m=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{j+k+m}}{\sqrt{j^2+k^2+m^2}},
$$
while the Madelung constant is
$$
M={\sum_{j,k,m=-\infty}^{\infty}}^\prime\frac{(-1)^{j+k+m}}{\sqrt{j^2+k^2+m^2}},
$$
with the $^\prime$ indicating that the term with $j=k=m=0$ is to be skipped.  Note that your sum accounts for one of the $8$ octants in the Madelung sum (the one with all positive coordinates), but skips all the terms with any coordinate equal to zero, and has an extra minus sign.  Filling in the missing terms, you can say that
$$
M=-8S+12\sum_{j,k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{j+k}}{\sqrt{j^2+k^2}}+6\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^j}{j}.
$$
The final sum is $-\log 2\approx -0.693147$, and the middle sum is (numerically) something like $0.2892 \pm 0.0001$; putting these together with OP's $S\approx 0.132476$ gives $M\approx -1.748 \pm 0.001$, which is close enough ... it agrees with the reported value of $M$, which is $-1.747565$ according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madelung_constant).

Comment: Thanks  @mjqxxxx  Could you explain a little detail how do you split  of the sum  S

Comment: $$\sum _{m=1}^{10} \sum _{k=1}^{10} \sum _{j=1}^{10} \frac{(-1)^{j+k+m} \left(j^2+k^2+m^2\right)}{\left(j^2+k^2+m^2\right)^{3/2}}=\sum _{m=-10}^{-1} \sum _{k=-10}^{-1} \sum _{j=-10}^{-1} \frac{(-1)^{j+k+m} \left(j^2+k^2+m^2\right)}{\left(j^2+k^2+m^2\right)^{3/2}}$$

Comment: Each variable, when summed from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, has three cases ... $-\infty$ to $-1$, zero, and $1$ to $\infty$.  The case where all variables are zero is skipped.  So the Madelung sum has $27-1=26$ cases to consider.  Of these, $6$ have two variables equal to zero, $12$ have one variable equal to zero, and $8$ have no variables equal to zero.  Because the summand is invariant under permutations of the variables and under switching signs of any variable, there are only three distinct sums to evaluate... but with coefficients $8,12,6$, as in the equation for $M$ given above.

Comment: Thanks very much @mjqxxxx

Comment: the following sum are